# ext js 4: too much recursion

Tags: javascript, extjs, recursion

I have two collapsible panels inside a tab one for "Search" and other one for "Results". From the results panel, I open a model window for editing.

Below is my workflow

- In the search panel, search
- When the search results are returned collapse the search panel and expand results panel and show results in the grid
- When user clicks on grid cell, new window is opened for editing
- When editing is submitted , the window is closed.
- A button called "Back to Search" can take you back to Search panel and can continue to search with new criteria

The problem is , when you click [Search] second time, nothing happens and FB shows "too much recursion"

Couldn't find the exact problem. looks like some events are stuck in the loop.

Can someone please give any hint to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Hint: Provide some source code.

Comment: I think we'll need to see some code for this one. PS. There should be no such thing as "too much recursion" ;-)

Comment: Also, probably even more importantly, a call stack.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error while working with Ext.tree.Panel component.
The problem was that **each item in tree must have unique id**. If two id's matched, the browser hangs on openning the tree and wrote:
ff: too much recursion, 
chrome: Maximum call stack size exceeded